# Celery cannot detect nodes

Tags: python, redis, celery

I've started a celery3 worker (Redis backend) on dev machine with a command like:
`celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info -E`
(and the celery screen says that events are enabled)

Then I try to get stats for this working with command:
`celery status`

which results in 
`Error: No nodes replied within time constraint`

What can be a possible cause for this?
I've already tried restarting the working and the machine.

Comment: Celery 3 nodes will not find celery 2 nodes, because the exchange has changed name.  See the whatsnew-3.0 in the documentation

Comment: I have Celery2 on the system but above I use only celery3 calls in a dedicated virtual env where celery3 (Chiastic Slide) was installed.